# Keeping Only Negative Values Across Multiple Columns in Data Frame

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

I have a large data frame with observations that are positive and negative. I want to only keep rows that have at least one negative value in one of the columns (since that indicates something is wrong with the data and needs to be cleaned). An example of the data frame is below.

```
Staff.Confirmed Residents.Confirmed Staff.Deaths Resident.Deaths Staff.Recovered Residents.Recovered          State
1                0                   1            0               0               0                   0        Alabama
2                0                   0            0               0               0                   0         Alaska
3                0                   0            0               1               0                   0        Arizona
4                0                 -61            0               0               0                   0       Arkansas
5               21                  41            0               0               0                   9     California
6                0                  15            0               0              -1                   1       Colorado
7                2                  15            0               0               1                  21
```

So I would want to keep an observation like Arkansas, which contains a negative value of -61 in one of its columns, but remove one like California, where none of the variables are negative.

Anyone know of a good way to do this? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `base R` solution:

```
#Create index
index <- which(names(df)=='State')
#Data
df$Var <- apply(df[,-index],1,function (x) length(which(x<0)))
#Filter
df2 <- df[df$Var!=0,]

Staff.Confirmed Residents.Confirmed Staff.Deaths Resident.Deaths Staff.Recovered Residents.Recovered    State
4               0                 -61            0               0               0                   0 Arkansas
6               0                  15            0               0              -1                   1 Colorado
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rowSums` to count number of values that are less than 0 and select rows where the value is atleast more than 1.

```
cols <- sapply(df, is.numeric)
df[rowSums(df[cols] < 0) > 0, ]


#  Staff.Confirmed Residents.Confirmed Staff.Deaths Resident.Deaths Staff.Recovered Residents.Recovered    State
#4               0                 -61            0               0               0                   0 Arkansas
#6               0                  15            0               0              -1                   1 Colorado
```

In `dplyr`, you can use `filter_if` which has been super-seeded but I still find it useful and simple to use in row-wise operations.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter_if(cols, any_vars(. < 0))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! When I try this, it gives me the following error:

`Error: .predicate has no matching columns.`

Not sure why it's not working? I changed the "State" variable slightly so it also includes the date of the observation in the name. Is that maybe messing it up?

Comment: Seems to work for the sample data shared. Does the base R solution work? Remember that `cols` should have `TRUE` for columns that you want to check negative values. Here I have taken all numerical columns in `cols`.

Answer (score 0):

Another base solution to find rowwise negative values: you can `do.call()` with `pmax()` (which flags values smaller than `0` in the list produced by `lapply()`). This should scale reasonably well for a large dataset, too.

```
df1[as.logical(do.call(pmax, lapply(df1[sapply(df1, is.numeric)], `<`, 0))), ]

  Staff.Confirmed Residents.Confirmed Staff.Deaths Resident.Deaths Staff.Recovered Residents.Recovered    State
4               0                 -61            0               0               0                   0 Arkansas
6               0                  15            0               0              -1                   1 Colorado
```

**Data**:

```
df1 <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "Staff.Confirmed Residents.Confirmed Staff.Deaths Resident.Deaths Staff.Recovered Residents.Recovered          State
1                0                   1            0               0               0                   0        Alabama
2                0                   0            0               0               0                   0         Alaska
3                0                   0            0               1               0                   0        Arizona
4                0                 -61            0               0               0                   0       Arkansas
5               21                  41            0               0               0                   9     California
6                0                  15            0               0              -1                   1       Colorado
7                2                  15            0               0               1                  21           Misc")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm getting the following error: 

`Error in (function (..., na.rm = FALSE)  : no arguments`

Not sure why. one of the above solutions worked for me but I am wondering why it's not working. pmax() is a base r function right? Thanks!

Comment: My guess is that `sapply(df1, is.numeric)` is the issue. Did you change `df1` to your dataframe name for your actual data? If you already checked that, make sure that (or whatever index you use) is selecting the columns you want to filter with